# display count of childs at recent parent in datatable using c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm fresher to c#. my aim is to show the count of child row nearest parent. I don't know how to to do please guide me.

[please check in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3Svz.png)

I'm showing the count of all children under 'trader'(which is the main parent)

'**raven**' and '**taj**' are the children of '**trader**'. data is handling in datatable.

raven and taj have children. I want to show the count of children under raven and taj.

please help me.

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far (code logic)

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < dtSingledimresult.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                   if (Regex.Matches(dtSingledimresult.Rows[i]["Description"].ToString(), "-").Count > 3)
                    {
                        rowsToCount.Add(dtSingledimresult.Rows[i]);
                    }
                } after that i dnot have any idea to do.

Comment: You can do a new loop after you have rowsToCount, to get the children

Comment: rowsToCount showing chlidrens without parents. tell me stop the loop where other parent come into loop